# Is there any way to automatically merge commits from master another branch whenever there is any merge request for master?

Tags: jenkins, gitlab

Is there any way to automatically merge commits from master another branch whenever there is any merge request for master?

want to add to JenkinsFile as well.

Comment: Hello and welcome. Why do you think this question belongs to the Unix/Linux site of StackExchange? This looks like a pure Gitlab/Jenkins administration thing to me.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.